# binding style value in angular JS for IE browser

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

i am working with progress bar for which slider values are being applied from API, for this i am using sytles to control the slider the part of code is given below , everything is working fine in chrome and firefox. but when i trying to run in IE progress bar values dont show up

```
<span class="progress-bar triggers" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: {{Math.round(KPIData.triggers * 100)}}%;"> </span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ngStyle` for that, see the [API reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngStyle).

`ngStyle` accepts a dictionary of keys (attribute names) and values (the value they should take, an empty string unsets them) rather than only a string. I think what you want is this:

```
<span class="progress-bar triggers" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="90" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" ng-style="{ 'width' : width}"></span>
```

And then in your controller:

```
$scope.width = Math.round(KPIData.triggers * 100)+'%';
```

This preserves the separation of template and the controller: the controller holds the semantic values while the template maps them to the correct attribute name.

Comment: i have tried ng-style , still having problems with IE browser

Comment: What kind of problems? Can you please create a plnkr?

Comment: problem is in IE browser the progress bar is is not showing the value marker

Comment: Thanks @ Johannes Jander